# Can't connect to Kafka Broker

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

Hi I can't connect to my kafka broker.
I have last version of Docker Desktop (running on windows) when I try use

```
Test-NetConnection localhost -port 9092
```

It returns:

```
TcpTestSucceeded : True
```

I try to use original docker-compose.yaml from https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.0.0-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml

I try to connect with https://github.com/rmoff/kafka-listeners/blob/master/python/python_kafka_test_client.py

I looked on https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/ but nothing helped. My scenario is Scenario 4.
I think it is all setup corectly but still got error:

```
KafkaError{code=_TRANSPORT,val=-195,str="Failed to get metadata: Local: Broker transport failure"}
```

======================================================

**EDIT**: I checked once more all things I tried before. And I realised that I hit used port for broker localhost listener twice... When I choose empty port all works

Comment: Have you try this? https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/#adding-new-listener  YOU must add some modification on an existing `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @J.Song Yes, I tried. Actually if I try same thing on another computers it works (ubuntu, working pc win10) .. :-/ 
At first I thought, I have blocked port 9092 so I rewrite it to 19092 but still no change and now I really don't know what to do or how to realise why I cant connect.

Comment: @J.Song actually all works. Look at edit part :-|